# bash file descriptors - script doesnt work as expected

Tags: bash, pipe, file-descriptor

So in my script I call other script that needs 2 lines as init arguments.

The problem is that in the following snippet, the "script.sh" only takes first line (arg1). It doesn't seem to do anything useful with second line (arg2)

```
fun () {
    arg1="init argument one"
    arg2="init argument two"

    local PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
    mkfifo $PIPE
    eval "exec 3<>${PIPE}"
    rm $PIPE

    ./script.sh <&3 &
    echo "$arg1">&3
    echo "$arg2">&3
}

fun
```

Also, script behaves the same when I delete last `echo`

```
fun () {
    arg1="init argument one"
    arg2="init argument two"

    local PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
    mkfifo $PIPE
    eval "exec 3<>${PIPE}"
    rm $PIPE

    ./script.sh <&3 &
    echo "$arg1">&3
}

fun
```

Comment: Which version of bash is this? You won't need the `eval` with a modern one. And `local` isn't valid syntax outside of function scope. And all-caps variable names are bad form -- see relevant POSIX convention at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: ...and, uhh, "need to use FDs"? **everything** uses FDs. `foo >bar` uses FDs. You might try to be more precise about the requirement.

Comment: ...backing up -- can you show the content of `script.sh`, or at least a minimal version of it sufficient to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: (As yet another note, `.sh` is not an appropriate extension for bash scripts; if they're executables, they shouldn't have any extension at all; if they're shell libraries, their extension should be `.bash` -- `.sh` implies that any POSIX interpreter can use them, ie. that they'll run correctly with `sh -x foo.sh`).

Comment: code taken from function scope. bash version 4.3.11

Comment: If it's taken from function scope, then either show that or fix it to work outside that scope -- that goes to the "complete" and "verifiable" parts of MCVE. [If you haven't yet, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; similarly, failing to include `test.sh` goes to the "complete" part].

Comment: You can just `exec 3<>$pipe`, no `eval` needed. Actually, you don't even need a modern bash for that -- what you'd need 4.1 or later for is for a `>&$fdnum` redirection.

Comment: BTW, remember how the code I gave you earlier closed FDs when it didn't need them? That's important -- if you don't do that properly, they won't correctly report EOF. And just because you opened something RW doesn't mean you can both read and write from that descriptor -- you only have one end of a FIFO open at a time.

Comment: ...notice how I put a one-line script into `bash -c '...'` in my answer instead of requiring an external `test.sh`, btw? That's part of providing a **complete, verifiable** example: Making sure that it can be run without needing separate files that aren't included.

Answer (score 2):

A FIFO has two sides, and each file descriptor is attached to only one side. That's true even when opened with `O_RDWR`, as you're doing with the `<>` operator; you can't **actually** both read and write from that single FD; it's simply a way to get a write handle without blocking for a reader to attach.

Thus, you must start a separate FD for your reader for the pipeline to work properly. Observe the following script's behavior, when run with at least two arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

# mktemp -u is insecure; better to use mktemp -d and create fifo w/in
# see the EXIT trap for automatic tempfile cleanup
trap 'rm -rf "$tempdir"' EXIT
tempdir=$(mktemp -d pipeline.XXXXXX)
mkfifo "$tempdir/pipe"

exec 3<>"$tempdir/pipe"
bash -c 'read -r a1; read -r a2; printf "Read: %q\n" "$a1" "$a2"' \
  <"$tempdir/pipe" 3>&- &
printf '%s\n' "$@" >&3
wait
```

Comment: Any reason to use `printf "... %q"` and not `%s`?

Comment: @andlrc, because `%q` will display otherwise-nonprintable characters in readable form.